# Stress Testing with Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, amazon-web-services, load

I am building a website with rails on AWS and I am trying to determine the best ways to stress-test while also getting some idea of the cost I will be paying by user (very roughly). I have looked at tools like Selerium and I am curious if I could do something similar with Postman.

My objects are:

1. Observe what kind of load the server would be under during the test, how the cpu and memory are affected.
2. See how the load generated would affect the cpu cycles on the system that would generate cost to me by AWS.

Through Postman I can easily generate REST calls to my rails server and simulate user interaction, If I created some kind of multithreaded application that would make many calls like to the server, would that be an efficient way to measure these objectives?

If not, is there a tool that would help me either either (or both) of these objectives?

thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BlazeMeter to do the load test.

This [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/performance-testing-in-continuous-delivery-using-aws-codepipeline-and-blazemeter/) show you how you can do it.